# Is there a translation of "troll"?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia, expressões-equivalentes

> 9. (Computer Science) computing a person who submits deliberately inflammatory articles to an internet discussion

Is there a Portuguese translation for this meaning of [**troll**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/troll)?

I was surprised to find a literal translation in the dictionary, [**trol**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/trol):

> 3. Indivíduo que coloca mensagens ou comentários provocadores em sítios de discussão pública on-line, com intuito desestabilizador.

However, I haven't seen this word being used in Portuguese before (besides from translation websites, Google is not providing examples in Portuguese). Wikipedia seems to register it as [troll](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_%28desambigua%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29) and the single l'ed *trol* was a [toy factory in Brazil](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trol).

Therefore, how do people refer to an "online" troll in Portuguese?

Comment: In Portugal we use [*gozão*](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/goz%C3%A3o)

Comment: @JorgeB. Acredito que somente se aplica ao pt-PT. Em pt-BR, a palavra "gozão" tem um sentido bem pejorativo. Então é bom não usá-la quando conversar com brasileiros.

Comment: @StriterAlfa eu sei ;)

Answer (score 7):

The word troll is used without being translated.

But I have seen very often people using the term *trolador*, which means the same as troll.

Also, people use the verb *trollar*, and sometimes *trolar*, which means make fun of someone (as you may see in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trollar)).

Comment: a versão correta é **trol**. Ver a minha resposta mais abaixo!

Answer (score 6):

As a brazilian, I also said "troll" sometimes talking with other person even in Portuguese. There are other words we don't translate, for example, *bullying* (meaning the coward acts often seen in schools towards other students intended to humiliate them...). Some terms related with technology, are used in english, like *trolls*, I've also heard the word *haters* (when someone in internet has the only purpose to be agressive, gor example in comments...) The word mouse (the computer mouse) is also not translated.

Comment: [As a Brazilian]

Answer (score 5):

Existe uma *gíria* em pt-BR para uma pessoa com esse tipo de comportamento: **"zueiro"** ou **"zoeiro"**. Você também poderá encontrar muitas vezes a palavra em forma de verbo também: **"zoar"**

Exemplo:

> "João zoou muito ao comentar em um site de culinária. João é zoeiro."
>
> "A zoeira não tem limites."

Comment: [The zoeira never ends.](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=the+zoeira+never+ends&client=safari&rls=en&dcr=0&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF3oyItc_WAhXLjZAKHYR7DVkQsAQIJQ&biw=1440&bih=815)

Comment: Mas zoeiro implica sempre algum tipo de humor; o *troll* puramente agressivo não é um zoeiro.

Answer (score 2):

The literal translation is "ogre" (pt-PT).

Comment: ogro e troll são monstros diferentes

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que **brincalhão** e **galhofeiro** sejam boas traduções.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the fact that the comprehensive answer is in Portuguese, but basically it justifies with reliable sources that the semantically and graphically correct Portuguese translation to "troll" is *trol*.

Quer o [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/trol), quer o dicionário da [Porto Editora](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/trol), têm a grafia **trol**, quer para a criatura do folclore nórdico, quer para o termo informático. Estes dois termos, aparentemente, têm étimos diferentes. O primeiro vem das línguas nórdicas, algo como um ogre, o segundo vem pela via do Francês, do verbo, *trôler* (vaguear), ou seja, com apenas um [l] e não com dois.

Esta grafia obedece às boas regras da fonética e da morfologia do Português, pois são, do ponto de vista silábico, similares a prol, gol, sol, farol, mongol, caracol ou lençol. Ademais, cito o Ciberdúvidas

> A palavra *troll* é de origem nórdica e chegou ao português através do
>   inglês, mas não se encontra averbada nos dicionários de língua
>   portuguesa por nós consultados. No folclore escandinavo, os trolls são
>   criaturas imaginárias, tão comuns nas histórias infantis como as
>   bruxas. De estatura variável (anões ou gigantes), os trolls são seres
>   geralmente malignos, feios ou estúpidos, que habitam em grutas ou
>   florestas e se transformam em pedra quando expostos aos raios solares.
>   Fora da mitologia escandinava, os trolls foram popularizados na ficção
>   pelo escritor britânico J. R. R. Tolkien. Pesquisas em motores de
>   busca da Internet revelam que as formas aportuguesadas **trol** e **trole**
>   (com o plural **tróis** e **troles**, respectivamente) têm já algumas
>   ocorrências, designando, para além da criatura imaginária, uma pessoa
>   pouco inteligente (ex.: Não perceberam nada, cambada de troles!) ou um
>   indivíduo que coloca mensagens ou comentários provocadores, maldosos
>   ou violentos em páginas de discussão pública on-line, com intuito
>   desestabilizador (ex.: Naquele blogue há muitos comentários de um trol
>   malcriado).

Ou seja, o trol informático, e o trol como criatura do folclore nórdico, têm étimos diferentes. Apesar do facto de os dois étimos serem diferentes, o verbo *to troll*, que deu origem ao termo informático, vem pela via do Francês, *trôler*, ou seja, com apenas um [l]. E mesmo que fosse unicamente anglófono, tal não justifica que não se adapte o termo à grafia da nossa língua, se tal já foi feito com tantas outras palavras. E este caso é muito simples, basta remover um [l], que todas as regras gráficas e fonéticas da língua se mantêm preservadas.

Answer (score 0):

O falante nativo de português brasileiro e — acredito — o falante nativo de português europeu também empregam o termo *gozador* e o vizinho *gozar*. Exs.:

1. Geringoncildo *gozou* tanto *com* os outros no fórum X, que a moderadora o baniu.
2. — Você *gozou* muito *com* a cara dos outros no fórum. Você está banido. — disse a moderadora.
3. "Pare de me *gozar*, por favor!"
4. — Você está me *gozando*, né?
5. "Que *gozador*! *Goza* até *com* ele mesmo!"

Pelo menos no Brasil, o verbo *gozar* quase sempre vem com a preposição *com*.

Answer (score 0):

I use “provocador” (= provocative, as in trouble-maker) or “trol”.

Answer (score -1):

In the sense of item 9, above (...intentional submittal of inflammatory comments
or articles to a forum or internet discussion.), I´d translate it into Portuguese
as "intriga", a feminine noun from the verb "intrigar" = fabricate malicious gossip or "fake news" aiming to generate conflict between or among people or nations.